# How to read sub Nodes from xml nodes list using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, xml-serialization, cxml

following is my cXML data, and able to load cxml data to xmlnodeslist from xml payload request, now i want to read all the sub nodes from xmlnodeslist following are the code which i am using to load xml data into xmlnodeslist and my cXML data.

```
 XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result);          
        string s = doc.DocumentElement.OuterXml;           
        doc.LoadXml(s);

        XmlNodeList nodes = doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//Credential");

        StringBuilder yourString = new StringBuilder();
        yourString.Append("The Products available are : ");         
        foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
        {
            yourString.Append(node["Name"].InnerText + ",");              
        }
        log.Debug("hemanth===========> outer" + yourString);
        return request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
```

Here is my cXML data

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<cXML timestamp="2017-04-06T05:44:31-04:00" version="1.2.0025" payloadID="ddae78e3-20b0-4f9d-91b8-7ca854f27568" xml:lang="en-US">
  <Header>
    <From>
      <Credential domain="NetworkId">
        <Identity>FakeIdentity</Identity>
      </Credential>
    </From>
    <To>
      <Credential domain="NetworkId">
        <Identity>FakeIdentity1</Identity>
      </Credential>
    </To>
    <Sender>
      <Credential domain="NetworkId">
        <Identity>FakeIdentity3</Identity>
        <SharedSecret>78910</SharedSecret>
      </Credential>
      <UserAgent>ServiceChannel Agent</UserAgent>
    </Sender>
  </Header>
  <Request>
    <OrderRequest>
      <OrderRequestHeader orderID="79491774" orderDate="2017-02-01T05:07:33-05:00" type="new">
        <Total>
          <Money currency="USD">700</Money>
        </Total>
        <ShipTo>
          <Address addressID="0000000000">
            <Name xml:lang="en-US">2115</Name>
            <PostalAddress name="Prudential Center">
              <DeliverTo>fatiha</DeliverTo>
              <Street>800 Boylston Street Suite 179 800 Boylston Street Suite 179</Street>
              <City>Boston</City>
              <State>MA</State>
              <PostalCode>02199</PostalCode>
              <Country isoCountryCode="US">US</Country>
            </PostalAddress>
            <Email name="default">fake@bn.com</Email>
            <Phone name="work">
              <TelephoneNumber>
                <CountryCode isoCountryCode="US">1</CountryCode>
                <AreaOrCityCode>617</AreaOrCityCode>
                <Number>111111</Number>
              </TelephoneNumber>
            </Phone>
          </Address>
        </ShipTo>
        <BillTo>
          <Address addressID="0000000000">
            <Name xml:lang="en-US">2115</Name>
            <PostalAddress name="Prudential Center">
              <DeliverTo>fatiha</DeliverTo>
              <Street>800 Boylston Street Suite 179 800 Boylston Street Suite 179</Street>
              <City>Boston</City>
              <State>MA</State>
              <PostalCode>02199</PostalCode>
              <Country isoCountryCode="US">US</Country>
            </PostalAddress>
            <Email name="default">fake@bn.com</Email>
            <Phone name="work">
              <TelephoneNumber>
                <CountryCode isoCountryCode="US">1</CountryCode>
                <AreaOrCityCode>617</AreaOrCityCode>
                <Number>2476959</Number>
              </TelephoneNumber>
            </Phone>
          </Address>
        </BillTo>
        <Extrinsic name="SubscriberID">2000000000</Extrinsic>
        <Extrinsic name="StoreNumber">0000</Extrinsic>
        <Extrinsic name="UserOrgDept">2000000000_0000</Extrinsic>
        <Extrinsic name="StoreEmail">fake@bn.com</Extrinsic>
        <Extrinsic name="StorePhone">000-000-0000</Extrinsic>
      </OrderRequestHeader>
      <ItemOut quantity="1" lineNumber="0">
        <ItemID>
          <SupplierPartID>00000000</SupplierPartID>
          <SupplierPartAuxiliaryID/>
        </ItemID>
        <ItemDetail>
          <UnitPrice>
            <Money currency="USD">41.4700</Money>
          </UnitPrice>
          <Description xml:lang="en-US">Heavy Duty Box Sealing Tape - CLEAR</Description>
          <UnitOfMeasure>EA</UnitOfMeasure>
          <Classification domain="SupplierPartID">00000000</Classification>
        </ItemDetail>
      </ItemOut>
      <ItemOut quantity="2" lineNumber="1">
        <ItemID>
          <SupplierPartID>000000</SupplierPartID>
          <SupplierPartAuxiliaryID/>
        </ItemID>
        <ItemDetail>
          <UnitPrice>
            <Money currency="USD">33.1500</Money>
          </UnitPrice>
          <Description xml:lang="en-US">Padded Mailers 9-1/2"X14-1/2"</Description>
          <UnitOfMeasure>EA</UnitOfMeasure>
          <Classification domain="SupplierPartID">000000</Classification>
        </ItemDetail>
      </ItemOut>
      <ItemOut quantity="1" lineNumber="2">
        <ItemID>
          <SupplierPartID>000000</SupplierPartID>
          <SupplierPartAuxiliaryID/>
        </ItemID>
        <ItemDetail>
          <UnitPrice>
            <Money currency="USD">27.5000</Money>
          </UnitPrice>
          <Description xml:lang="en-US">Bubble Mailers 12-1/2" x 19"</Description>
          <UnitOfMeasure>EA</UnitOfMeasure>
          <Classification domain="SupplierPartID">000000</Classification>
        </ItemDetail>
      </ItemOut>
      <ItemOut quantity="1" lineNumber="3">
        <ItemID>
          <SupplierPartID>00000000</SupplierPartID>
          <SupplierPartAuxiliaryID/>
        </ItemID>
        <ItemDetail>
          <UnitPrice>
            <Money currency="USD">40.5000</Money>
          </UnitPrice>
          <Description xml:lang="en-US">Pallet Shrinkwrap</Description>
          <UnitOfMeasure>EA</UnitOfMeasure>
          <Classification domain="SupplierPartID">00000000</Classification>
        </ItemDetail>
      </ItemOut>
    </OrderRequest>
  </Request>
</cXML>
```

Can anyone help to do this,

Thanks,
Venkat.

Comment: You seem to be reading all the sub nodes in your for loop. What exactly do you want to do with your sub nodes that you are currently unable to?

Comment: for example  <cXML timestamp="2017-04-06T05:44:31-04:00" version="1.2.0025" payloadID="ddae78e3-20b0-4f9d-91b8-7ca854f27568" xml:lang="en-US"> in this i need timestamp value and payloadId value.. like that i need all the values from the cxml? so how i get that,can u please explain....! thanks in advance,venkat

Comment: XmlNodeList nodes = doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//Credential");  Can you please suggest me the above will work to read the nodes please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
string timeStamp = node.Attributes["timestamp"].Value;
```

For example, this will print out every Credential "domain" and their Identity values:

```
XmlNodeList nodes = doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//Credential");

foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
{
    var identity = node.SelectSingleNode("Identity").InnerText;
    yourString.Append(node.Attributes["domain"].Value + "|" + identity + ",");              
}
```

Comment: foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
        {
            yourString.Append(node["Name"].InnerText + ",");              
        }     here the nodes are not getting anything and pointer is not entering into foreach block

Comment: First you'll have to find the exact node you want. And then run the code in my answer.

Comment: XmlNodeList nodes = doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//Credential"); Can you please suggest me the above will work to read the nodes please?

Comment: Now i am getting the domain values under Credential                  <From>
      <Credential domain="NetworkId">
        <Identity>FakeIdentity</Identity>
      </Credential>
    </From>
    <To>
      <Credential domain="NetworkId">
        <Identity>FakeIdentity1</Identity>
      </Credential>
    </To>  but to get identity value it is not working

Comment: I have updated my answer to include getting the value of the Identity node under the Credential. Any other details you need to get, can be done by reusing the examples I have given you.

Comment: Thanks Tom, I am able to get all the values using above except timestamp and version payloadid form below <cXML timestamp="2017-04-06T05:44:31-04:00" version="1.2.0025" payloadID="ddae78e3-20b0-4f9d-91b8-7ca854f27568" xml:lang="en-US"> Can you please help on this as well

Comment: Can you use "doc.Root" to get to that node?

Comment: Hi @Venkat , were you able to solve your problem? If my answer helped at all please upvote it, or even consider marking it as the answer